# can't render array of images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm trying to render a product card when clicking on it from a catalog. The product card has several images which are represented as an array in my db.json. The problem is that I get "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" error when trying to render item.img[0] or item.img[1] or item.img[2].

```
const Product = () => {

    const { id } = useParams();
    const [item, setItem] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/items/${id}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((item) => setItem(item));
        console.log(item)
    }, [id]);


    return(
        <ProductContainer className='container'>
            <ProductPath>Home/Product</ProductPath>
            <h2 className='title'>Product</h2>
            <ProductWrap>
                <div>{item.title}</div>
                <div>{item.brand}</div>
                <ProductLargeImage src = {item.img[0]}></ProductLargeImage>
            </ProductWrap>
        </ProductContainer>
    )
}
```

This is a part of my db.json

```
{
    "items": [
      { "id": 1,
      "title": "abstract mesh slash neck maxi dress",
      "category": "dress",
      "type": "women",
      "img": ["https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-abstract-mesh-slash-neck-maxi-dress/205484210-1-multi?$n_640w$&wid=513&fit=constrain", "https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-abstract-mesh-slash-neck-maxi-dress/205484210-3?$n_640w$&wid=513&fit=constrain", "https://images.asos-media.com/products/asos-design-abstract-mesh-slash-neck-maxi-dress/205484210-4?$n_640w$&wid=513&fit=constrain"],
      "price":"28.00",
      "color":"multi",
      "brand": "ASOS DESIGN",
      "isTrending": "false",
      "isFavorite": "false",
      "isBestseller": "false",
      "isInCart": "false"
    },

    { "id": 2,
      "title": "abstract floral print slash neck maxi dress",
      "category": "dress",
      "type": "women",
      "img": ["https://images.asos-media.com/products/collusion-abstract-floral-print-slash-neck-maxi-dress-in-multi/205236950-1-multi?$n_640w$&wid=513&fit=constrain", "https://images.asos-media.com/products/collusion-abstract-floral-print-slash-neck-maxi-dress-in-multi/205236950-4?$n_640w$&wid=513&fit=constrain", "https://images.asos-media.com/products/collusion-abstract-floral-print-slash-neck-maxi-dress-in-multi/205236950-4?$n_640w$&wid=513&fit=constrain"],
      "price":"27.99",
      "color": "blue",
      "brand": "COLLUSION",
      "isTrending": "true",
      "isFavorite": "false",
      "isBestseller": "false",
      "isInCart": "false"
    },
...]}
```

If I don't try to render array of images everything works fine, i get {item.title}, {item.brand} and other info. If I don't use an array and store only one image link in db.json everything works fine as well.
What should I fix? Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure every `item` has _at least_ one image path in its `img` array? Looks like some `item` objects may either have `img` set to `null` or the key-value pair does not exist on the `item`.

Comment: What is the output of " console.log(item)"?

Comment: @Gishas I get empty object if I don't try to render the array. If I try render the array i get only the error

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yes I'm sure... each object has an array with 3 img links. I also noticed that my images from the array are rendered if I do following: 
-remove src={item.img[0]} and render other info from item
-then write in VScode src={item.img[0]}. My images are rendered. But if Irefresh page I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

> @Gishas I get empty object if I don't try to render the array. If I
> try render the array i get only the error

Ok, so that is the problem, an empty object. You cannot access img[0] of an empty object, that is as it seems exactly what the error says.

Instead, I would console log that 'response.json' in

```
 .then((response) => response.json())
```

like e.g.

```
 .then((response) => { response.json().then(item => {
console.log('ITEM', item) 
setItem(item)
})
```

and try to figure out is there relevant data there and then try to use it for rendering.

Give it a shot.

Comment: I get corresponding object as it should be, I also get array of images (console.log(item.img)) and images separately (console.log(item.img[0] and so on). But the error does't fixed, still can't get the image here - <ProductLargeImage src = {item.img[0]}></ProductLargeImage> :(

Comment: 1. I suppose u used this code of mine, or similar based on it and it still give an error?
2. What error do you get now, precise details please? What does it mead you "can't get the image here"? Image not rendered despite you having array of images now, or you get undefined again on img[0]?
3. What is ProductLargeImage? Separate component, styled-component, etc?